# Unable to start activity with Theme.Dialog

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, android-theme

I don't know how to handle this, I think I've search everywhere.. But this problem is just mysterious,. I got an activity named EditdataActivity

```
public class EditdataActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    logclass clogs = new logclass();
    EditText edt_ln;
    EditText edt_lat;
    EditText edt_long;
    Button btn_cancel;
    Button btn_save;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_dataedit);
        clogs =(logclass) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyClass");
        edt_ln = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_Ln);
        edt_lat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_lat);
        edt_long = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.det_long);
        btn_cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel_btn);
        btn_save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_save);

        edt_ln.setText(clogs.getname());
        edt_lat.setText(clogs.getlatloc()+"");
        edt_long.setText(clogs.getlongloc()+"");

        OnClickListener savelistener = new OnClickListener() {          
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //notifpopup("Save changes?");
             }
        };
        btn_save.setOnClickListener(savelistener);     

        OnClickListener cancellistener = new OnClickListener() {            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(EditdataActivity.this, AdddataclassActivity.class);
                intent1.putExtra("MyClass", clogs);  
                intent1.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);   
                startActivity(intent1);
                overridePendingTransition (R.anim.open_main, R.anim.close_next);
             }
        };
        btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(cancellistener);

    }

    void notifpopup(String notif){
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle(notif);
        alert.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                clogs.setname(edt_ln.getText().toString());
                double lat = Double.parseDouble(edt_lat.getText().toString());
                double longl = Double.parseDouble(edt_long.getText().toString());
                clogs.setlatloc(lat);
                clogs.setlongloc(longl);
            }
        });

        alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    }
           });

            alert.show();
    }   
}
```

and this is called from this activity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ........
        clogs =(logclass) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("MyClass");
        ........   

           Button edit_data = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_addattrbdel);
           OnClickListener editlistener = new OnClickListener() {           
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    gotoeditview();
                 }
            };
            edit_data.setOnClickListener(editlistener); 
    }

    void gotoeditview(){
        Intent intentl = new Intent(this,EditdataActivity.class);
        intentl.putExtra("MyClass", clogs);  
        intentl.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
        startActivity(intentl);
        overridePendingTransition (R.anim.appear, R.anim.disappear);
    }
```

however an error occured when I execute it as shown in the logcat beloc

```
10-17 17:06:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(707): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 17:06:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(707): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ict.map_navigation/com.ict.map_navigation.EditdataActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
10-17 17:06:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2070)
10-17 17:06:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2095)
10-17 17:06:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:134)
10-17 17:06:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1203)
10-17 17:06:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-17 17:06:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-17 17:06:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4830)
10-17 17:06:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-17 17:06:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-17 17:06:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
10-17 17:06:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
10-17 17:06:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-17 17:06:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(707): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
10-17 17:06:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(707):  at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:110)
10-17 17:06:41.750: E/AndroidRuntime(707): ....
```

.. however as what I've read on some suggested solution I changed my EditdataActivity to Acitvity.. it did not have any errors.. but it only displays this ..

[image]

and my xml file for that activity is this..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Change Name of the Location" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_Ln"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/edt_Ln"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Change Location" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="Longitude:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:text="Latitude:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_lat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/det_long"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/edt_lat"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_save"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/det_long"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btn_cancel"
        android:background="#00ced1"
        android:text="Save" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_cancel"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/btn_save"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn_save"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
        android:background="#ff0000"
        android:text="Cancel" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have other activity which is exactly like this in my project. but they all work fine, I tried.. Restarting my eclipse IDE.. but it did not work.. Please help, maybe I just forgot something. thanks.. and here is the Manifest file of my project..

Sorry for my long post...

Comment: what is thr in ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:110,  and post ur ActionBarActivityDelegate.java file too.

Comment: IllegalStateException, Thrown when an action is attempted at a time when the VM is not in the correct state.

Comment: follow this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity

Comment: I guess its from my android-support-v7-appcompat.jar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create your own custom dialogs, create class who extends `DialogFragment` instead of creating activities. It's easy to use and you don't have to declare them in your manifest.

Use it like this:

```
public class EditDataDialog extends DialogFragment {

    // Properties here
    .....

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_dataedit, container, false);

        // Properties init here
        .....

        return view;
    }
}
```

Then, in your main activity, call this:

```
// Show the "edit data" dialog
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
EditDataDialog editDataDialog = new EditDataDialog();
editDataDialog.show(fm, "edit_data_dialog");
```

Comment: I think I'd rather use this method.. than using another activity.. its more easier to handle.. thanks...

Comment: Good, happy to be useful :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use **ActionBarActivity**, its theme must be a `Theme.AppCompat` theme (or descendant).

If you want to use `Theme.Dialog` theme, your activity should not extend **ActionBarActivity**.